# Write a Scheme procedure sum of the odd number

Tags: scheme, racket, procedure

Write a Scheme procedure that takes a list and returns the sum of the odd numbers in the list.
For example, (sumodd '(1 (2 () 6) 3 (5) 2)) returns 9

**Here are my code**

```
(define (sumodd ls)
(cond ((null? ls) 0)
      ((list? (car ls)) (sumodd (car ls)))
      ((= (modulo (car ls) 2) 1)) (+ (car ls) (sumodd (cdr ls)))
      (else (sumodd (cdr ls)))))
```

I tried my best but can not get the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

In he second term you check if the `car` of the list is a list. eg. `((5) 3 1)`. What would happen with `(3 1)` when you just sum the list `(5)`? Shouldn't the logic be to add together the results of `sumodd` on both the `car` and `cdr`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code, reformatted for clarity, is

```
(define (sumodd ls)
  (cond
    ((null? ls)
     #| case1: |#   0                  )
    ((list? (car ls))
     #| case2: |#   (sumodd (car ls))  )
    ((= (modulo (car ls) 2) 
        1)
     #| case3: |#    #| no code |#     )
    (+
     #| case4: |#   (car ls)
                    (sumodd (cdr ls))  )
    (else
     #| else: |#    (sumodd (cdr ls))  )  ))
```

As you can see, besides the issue in case2 mentioned in the other answer, where you really should add the `sumodd` of `(cdr ls)` to the `sumodd` of the `(car ls)` which you have, there's also the issue of wrong parentheses in case3 which causes it to split into two erroneous cases, 3 and 4.

But actually, since a list isn't an odd number, another valid choice there is to just `sumodd` the numbers in the `cdr` of `ls`, not in the `car` as you have.

Back to the erroneous cases, the first one, case3, says to always just return `#t` if the `car` of `ls` is odd.

The second, `case4,` tests whether `+` is a falsy value. Which if course it is not, so this case, if reached, will always be taken. But then it won't call the `+` function, since `+` will have already served its role as the value being tested. The body of that clause consists of two expressions. The first is ignored, and the second evaluated and its value returned.

All this was just in error. The corrected code as was probably intended, is

```
(define (sum-odd-numbers ls)
  (cond 
      ((null? ls)               0)
      ((list? (car ls))         (sumodd (cdr ls)))    ; cdr, not car
                         ; or do the other thing and add cdr and car
      ((= (modulo (car ls) 2) 
          1)
                    (+ (car ls) (sumodd (cdr ls))) )
      (else                     (sumodd (cdr ls))  )))
```

I've also renamed the function. Naming is important.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define sum-odd
  (lambda (l)
    (fold-right (lambda (x a)
                  (if (list? x)
                      (+ a (sum-odd x))
                      (if (odd? x)
                          (+ a x)
                          a)))
                0
                l)))
```

Comment: This answer was flagged for review as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality) and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not good answers** and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted  because they are **not useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / better than existing answers (if there are any). [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29832322)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney this might be the policy but the above (automatic?) blurb is just wrong. this answer is still useful. a learner sees the (correct, working) code, sees functions new to them, consults the docs, learns. useful.