# Scheme Adding odd elements within a list of a list

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to add all the odd atoms within my list within lists, in order to get every odd atom and add them together. I'm getting an error that says:

+: contract violation
expected: number?
given: ()

So I'm assuming I'm getting to the end of my list and throwing a null list at the addition? But I'm unsure how to fix this or get around this.

```
(define (sumodd list)
  (cond ((null? list) 0)
        
        ((list? (car list)) (sumodd (cdr list)))
        ((odd? (car list))
           (+ (car list) (sumodd (cdr list))))
        (sumodd (cdr list))
         
  ))

(sumodd '(1 (2 () 6) 3 (5) 8))
```

Comment: just thought I'd add, that I have seen similar problems like this on StackOverflow, but the solutions on those threads gave the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write a Scheme procedure sum of the odd number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69186029/write-a-scheme-procedure-sum-of-the-odd-number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, don't use symbol `list` as name of variable. Value of `list` is `#<procedure:list>` and when you rewrite this value, you will be unable to use that function. See example:

```
(define (testlist list)
  (list list))

(testlist (list 1 2 3))
```

Your solution has two errors:

1. When `(list? (car lst))`, you have to sum together `(car lst)` and `(cdr lst)`.
2. You are missing `else` clause in last branch of `cond`.

Solution:

```
(define (sumodd lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)        
        ((list? (car lst)) (+ (sumodd (car lst))
                              (sumodd (cdr lst))))
        ((odd? (car lst)) (+ (car lst)
                             (sumodd (cdr lst))))
        (else (sumodd (cdr lst)))))

(sumodd '(1 (2 () 6) 3 (5) 8))
```

This result can be also achieved with:

```
(require racket/list)

(define (sumodd2 lst)
  (apply + (filter odd? (flatten lst))))

(sumodd2 '(1 (2 () 6) 3 (5) 8))
```